# Any happy IE8 users with civicrm image display issues?

Tags: images, contact-image

We've discovered an issue while trying to display civicrm contact image via Drupal Views in Internet Explorer 8,  it shows famous red cross instead of image; interesting thing happens when direct image url is being loaded, here is it:   [image: ie8 tries to access civicrm image]

We're aware that currently (CiviCRM 4.6)  ImageCache presets don't play nice with Civicrm image (there are civicrm forum discussions here: https://forum.civicrm.org/index.php?topic=34929.0 and here: https://forum.civicrm.org/index.php?topic=32232.0 ) but no clear resolution so far.
We realize it's quite historical and rare case nowadays, however, have hope someone out here might be able to shed some light on this.

Comment: Here's an exact case discussed http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/ie/forum/ie8-windows_other/internet-explorer-doesnt-display-jpg-files/2e46f561-62f5-416b-9d8d-221d90a25e24?auth=1   where it has claimed to be an issue with jpg saved from Adobe Illustrator.. not sure it's the case though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not exactly a fix, but rather a workaround: https://www.drupal.org/project/imagecache_external module has been used for an additional image pre-processing. Images processed by drupal imagecache module work just fine in IE8.